# order of calling constructors in Python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Parent(object):        # define parent class
   parentAttr = 100
   def __init__(self):
      print "Calling parent constructor"

   def parentMethod(self):
      print 'Calling parent method'

   def setAttr(self, attr):
      Parent.parentAttr = attr

   def getAttr(self):
      print "Parent attribute :", Parent.parentAttr


class Child(Parent): # define child class
   def __init__(self):
      print "Calling child constructor"

   def childMethod(self):
      print 'Calling child method'


c = Child()          # instance of child
```

I have called created an instance of the Child class here.It doesn't seem to call the constructor of the parent class.The output looks like shown below.

```
Calling child constructor
```

In C++ for example when you call the constructor of a derived class the base class constructor get called first.Why is this not happening in Python?

Comment: `__init__` isn't a constructor, it's a ... drumroll ... _initialiser_!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Should Python call the parent constructor before or after the child constructor?  With what arguments?  Not knowing, it leaves it to you to decide.

```
class Child(Parent): # define child class
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()  # call the appropriate superclass constructor
        print "Calling child constructor"
```

See also [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/1558890) for the benefits of using `super()`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to explicity call the parent constructor in the [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method of the child class. Try:

```
class Child(Parent): # define child class
   def __init__(self):
      Parent.__init__(self)
      print "Calling child constructor"
```

Comment: While this will work in this trivial case, once you get into multi-inheritance, it is rather brittle. Better to use `super`, per Jim Garrison's answer, which will be equivalent here, and continue to do the right thing in more complex cirumstances.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Python 3.x, you can run this instead (it is nearly what you are doing in your own code):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    c = Child()
    c.method_a()
    c.method_b()
    c.get_attr()
    c.set_attr(200)
    Child().get_attr()

class Parent:

    static_attr = 100

    def __init__(self):
        print('Calling parent constructor')

    def method_a(self):
        print('Calling parent method')

    def set_attr(self, value):
        type(self).static_attr = value

    def get_attr(self):
        print('Parent attribute:', self.static_attr)

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Calling child constructor')
        super().__init__()

    def method_b(self):
        print('Calling child method')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```